# Word Shuts down immediately after open; cannot find the file its trying to open

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Everytime I start Microsoft Word 2k7 on a Vista OS, The program attempts to start, stops, then states that it has encountered an error and needs to be shut down. I decline sending the error report, and am immediately prompted by a dialog box that states that the file I was trying to open cannot be found. This is true for every file that I open with Word. Tried reinstalling office, to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Remove any add-ins you may have.
- Start Word in Safe Mode with `winword.exe /a` from the Run menu.

More at this site: http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/troubleshootin1/qt/safemode.htm

**EDIT:**

Uninstall Office 2007 using this [Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218) link from Microsoft Support.

Comment: sadly it din't work. I tried safe mode and the program still wouldn't fix. Office went through the "Detect and Repair" process, stated a successful operation and yet still wouldn't work.

Comment: Added the fix it link from MS Support.